How to use kubectl command to do hard refresh in ArgoCD?
I am using ArgoCD Vault Plugin for my application.
I would like to do a hard refresh to get new secrets when triggering a deployment from my pipeline.
I know I can do it with ArgoCD command but there are some complications involved for authentication from CI system.
I feel it is possible to use kubectl path to do the hard refresh but I can't figure out how.

Answering my own question, it can be done with
kubectl annotate app/my-app argocd.argoproj.io/refresh="hard"

Got the idea from here https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/annotations-and-labels/
